# Count occurrences within N days from current time - pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very simple problem. I have a long list of IDs and timestamps of occurrence, I want to count the timestamps in certain time windows, by ID. Here is the sample data:

```
+---------------+-------------------+
|             id|         Occurrence|
+---------------+-------------------+
|533ladk203ldpwk|2018-03-28 17:52:04|
|516dlksw9823adp|2018-03-26 12:58:04|
|516dlksw9823adp|2018-01-24 07:52:16|
|533ladk203ldpwk|2018-03-18 03:23:11|
|533ladk203ldpwk|2018-03-14 08:30:13|
+---------------+-------------------+
```

This is what I want in return:

```
+---------------+-------------------------+
|             id|Last30daysOccurrenceCount|
+---------------+-------------------------+
|533ladk203ldpwk|                        3|
|516dlksw9823adp|                        1|
+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Is there a simple way to do this using PySpark or SQL?

Comment: you might wanna check tutorials. Lot of examples on `count` `group by` `order` by on `RDD` . Also `map-reduce` with lambda would do the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current timestamp using [`pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp) and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.datediff()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.datediff) to compute the difference between it and the value in `"Occurrence"`.

For example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn('days_since_today', f.datediff(f.current_timestamp(), f.col("Occurrence")))\
    .show()
#+---------------+-------------------+----------------+
#|             id|         Occurrence|days_since_today|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------------+
#|533ladk203ldpwk|2018-03-28 17:52:04|               5|
#|516dlksw9823adp|2018-03-26 12:58:04|               7|
#|516dlksw9823adp|2018-01-24 07:52:16|              68|
#|533ladk203ldpwk|2018-03-18 03:23:11|              15|
#|533ladk203ldpwk|2018-03-14 08:30:13|              19|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

Then you can filter out the rows that meet the conditon that `"days_since_today"` is less than or equal to 30, group by the `"id"` and count.

```python
df.withColumn('days_since_today', f.datediff(f.current_timestamp(), f.col("Occurrence")))\
    .where("days_since_today <= 30")\
    .groupBy('id')\
    .agg(f.count("Occurrence").alias("Last30daysOccurrenceCount"))\
    .show()
#+---------------+-------------------------+
#|             id|Last30daysOccurrenceCount|
#+---------------+-------------------------+
#|533ladk203ldpwk|                        3|
#|516dlksw9823adp|                        1|
#+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Or equivalently, without the intermediate column:

```python
df.groupBy('id')\
    .agg(
        f.sum(
            f.when(
                f.datediff(f.current_timestamp(), f.col("Occurrence")) <= 30,
                1
            ).otherwise(0)
        ).alias("Last30daysOccurrenceCount")
    )\
    .show()
#+---------------+-------------------------+
#|             id|Last30daysOccurrenceCount|
#+---------------+-------------------------+
#|533ladk203ldpwk|                        3|
#|516dlksw9823adp|                        1|
#+---------------+-------------------------+
```